# ListView ID called on null? (Kotlin)

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-listview

I'm new to Kotlin and im trying to build a `HomePage` where there is a `BottomNavigation` with 3 `Fragment` pages but in 1 of the pages I set a `ListView` and whenever I call the ID it gives the following errer(`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: categoryListView must not be null`)

Here is how Im calling it in my HomePage which is where the content appears:

```
class HomePage : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    lateinit var adapter : CategoryAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)

        adapter = CategoryAdapter(this, DataService.categories)
        categoryListView.adapter = adapter

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.Bottom_Nav_Home -> {
                println("Home pressed")
                replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.Bottom_Nav_Notifs -> {
                println("Notification pressed")
                replaceFragment(NotifsFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.Bottom_Nav_List -> {
                println("List pressed")
                replaceFragment(ListFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.NavPageFragment, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

am I doing it correct? or am I supposed to call the categoryListView elsewhere? because I tried in my `ListFragment` which is where my activity code is and it gave a context error

here is how the Fragment activity looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Bottom_List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.ListFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categoryListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the `categoryListView` resolved inside the activity but it is (as far as I understand) part of the fragment. This simply does not work.

The `CategoryAdapter` and the `ListView` should be used inside your `HomeFragment` class and this will work then.

So move this code into your fragment:

```
adapter = CategoryAdapter(this, DataService.categories)
categoryListView.adapter = adapter
```

*Update*

I would move it into the `onViewCreated()` method. There you can simply rely on the fact that there is a view available with a context.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    adapter = CategoryAdapter(view.context, DataService.categories)
    categoryListView.adapter = adapter // categoryListView will be not null here
}
```

Comment: The issue in putting the code in the fragment is that it requires me to give context and I tried multiple methods and nothing works, is the way im building the page wrong by any means? can you please explain a little deeper about moving the CategoryAdapter and listView into the HomeFragment

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple way to get the context